# Незамкнутый многоугольник в yandex maps jsapi. Как закрасить область выше определенных линий?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Возникла проблема с рисованием многоугольника. Суть в том, что на карте рисуются сектора направлений север, северо-восток, восток и т.д. Линии направлений рисуются со свойством geodesic: true. После этого некоторые сектора закрашиваются в красный, для этого рисуются многоугольники по тем же точкам, что и линии направлений и тоже с geodesic:true. Но на картах гугл сектор севера закрашивается правильно, он бесконечно рисует многоугольник, ограничивая его заданными точками. А на картах яндекс многоугольник либо рисуется только частично, либо совсем съезжает.

на первой картинке как отображает многоугольник Яндекс и синие метки, по которым он строится:

[image]
 
 
иногда рисует так:

[image]
  
  
и то как по тем же самым точкам рисует гугл:

[image]
 
 
можно ли как-то заставить яндекс рисовать также как гугл?

код, который рисует полигон в Яндекс:

```
polygon_ya[i] = new ymaps.Polygon([triCoords5],{}, {
    fill: true,
    stroke: false,
    fillColor: fillcolor,
    fillOpacity: fillopa,
    geodesic: true
});
map_var.geoObjects.add(polygon_ya[i]);
```

Пример рисования: http://jsfiddle.net/aeqskzdn/23/

Comment: Попробуйте для геометрии полигона поставить coordRendering: 'straightPath' Документация: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/geometry.Polygon-docpage/#param-options.coordRendering Выглядеть должно примерно так: polygon_ya[i].geometry.options.set('coordRendering', 'straightPath'); Вообще проще будет помочь, если вы соберёте пример где-нибудь, на jsfiddle например.

Comment: coordRendering: 'straightPath' ставила, всё еще больше едет. Попробую собрать примерчик

Comment: Кажется, что без промежуточных точек тут не обойтись http://jsfiddle.net/dLwpy8hv/